# Want to filter XML/RSS by Week day with PHP

Tags: php, xml

First I'd like to say that I'm very new with PHP. I have an xml file: http://www.anewmandesigns.com/RSSseptember2013.xml

In the feed, I'm trying to just display Wednesday's dates (the actual entries) in the month of September (4th, 11th, 18th, and the 25th) on my website using PHP. Here's my code... how can I modify?

```
<?php

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.anewmandesigns.com/oakshade/calendar/rss/RSSseptember2013.xml');
    $feed = array();

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) 
    {
        $item = array (
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }

    $limit = 5;

    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) 
    {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date'])); 
        $year = substr($timestamp, 0, 4);
        $month = date(' M ', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        $day = date(' d ', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p>'.$month.'<span> '.$day.'</span></p>';
        echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$description.'</a></p>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following conditional statement to check if it's a Wednesday:

```
if ( date('l', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']) ) == 'Wednesday') { 
    # code ...
}
```

For checking if it's September:

```
if ( date('F', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']) ) == 'September') { 
    # code ...
}
```

---

Full code:

```
<?php

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.anewmandesigns.com/oakshade/calendar/rss/RSSseptember2013.xml');
    $feed = array();

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) 
    {
        $item = array (
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );

        //echo date('l', strtotime($item['date']))."\n";    
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }

    $limit = 5;

    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) 
    {
        if ( date('l', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']) ) == 'Wednesday')
        {  //  if it is wednesday, proceed

            $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
            $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
            $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];    

            $year = date('Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            $month = date('M', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
            $day = date('d', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

            echo '<p>'.$month.'<span> '.$day.'</span></p>';
            echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$description.'</a></p>';    
        }
    }

?>
```

Notes:

- Note that you didn't have the `$timestamp` variable defined anywhere and I've changed it to get the year directly from the `pubDate` field.
- In the XML file you posted, there aren't any items posted on Wednesday, so the above code would not output anything, but if you change it to a different week day,  it should work.
- The current XML file's dates are all in September, so I've avoided the conditional check in the code, but if you want to check the month as well, you can add it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amal, Here is my website, you can see http://www.anewmandesigns.com/oakshade/calendar/ under Wednesday's Activites... there must be something I'm missing. Again I really appreciate your help. Christopher, using '0' instead of '093'  gave me september's Sunday events- which is also something i was trying to do! :)

Comment: @Anew3469: Sorry? What's the issue?

Comment: In my xml document, I have events throughout the month of September. I'd like to only display the items that fall on Wednesday. Christopher's first example gave the events that fell on Sunday. If I tries to edit that code, I got December 31st events....

Comment: @Anew3469: Did you read the whole answer? I don't think there are any events that fall on Wednesday, in the XML file you posted.

Comment: <b>Prayer Meeting & Bible Study</b> - 9/18/2013 - 7:30 PM to 9:00 PM<br /><br /> is just one, I think. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Anew3469: Nope, that's a Thursday. See this paste for all days: http://pastie.org/8303622

Comment: I'm not sure how that is, but here's my calendar : http://www.mychurchevents.com/calendar/calendar.aspx?list_by=calendar_month&ci=L6F0H2N8H2F0O9L6I3&igd

Comment: @Anew3469: I'm not sure how your Calendar is relevant here. You have an XML file with some data, and all this code does is parse and display the information using PHP -- your XML file does **not** have any Wednesdays, it therefore would not output anything. However, if you change the `if` statement to a different day (one from http://pastie.org/8303622) -- it will and should work. For example, try this: `if ( date('l', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']) ) == 'Sunday')` -- I've tested it, and it produces the expected output.

Comment: the pubdate is different from the date of the event (I provided an xml output of the online calendar)... which may be the source of the confusion... but event_date is what we are looking for: 'date' I apologize for any frustration! I certainly am appreciative for your help

Comment: yes, thank you-- changing the feed limit and the item to start on fixed the issue. Very appreciative for your time, and Christopher's!!

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code ...

```
if(date('mw', strtotime($item['date'])) == '093'){
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
```

EDIT: I have updated the code to only show september

Comment: find `array_push($feed, $item);` and replace it with the code I gave you.

Comment: I went ahead and added the code and it gave me all december 31st entries: if(date('mw', strtotime($item['date'])) == '093'){
    array_push($feed, $item);
}